# Remote desktop stops receiving input (hangs) periodically

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, lan

I am working with MS remote desktop feature, from windows 8 notebook client and windows 8.1 as a desktop server (running windows 8.1 prof).

The connection is over LAN, speed indicators are all excellent.

With the period of 30 seconds, remote desktop stops to receive input. I.e. no buttons are available for pressing, no hover events occur, not textual input possible.

Simultaneously, output works fine, for example, if some animation on web page, it continues to run.

How to find a reason of this and how to fix this?

**UPDATE**

How is it possible to trace and debug input responsiveness?

**UPDATE 2**

With more statistics I found that output can also hang. I.e. animations may freeze.

Need to say that notebook is connected by WiFi. So it looks like WiFi is reconnecting twice per minute. Although it is not explicitly visible.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Windows 8 at first. I ran the update via control panel, on all Windows 8 machines, and that fixed it. Make sure access the updates via control panel and not under change PC settings. [image]

Comment: Everything is up to date on my case.

Comment: Are you saying that you ran Windows Updates on all machines?

Comment: Yes, I did it, true

Comment: Are the 8.1 that you are using the full version? Or are they previews? If they are not the full version that will cause a problem, since the preview is set to expire tomorrow.